# Bert Model Compile Error - TypeError: Invalid keyword argument(s) in `compile`: {'steps_per_execution'}

Tags: python, tensorflow, bert-language-model

I have been using bert and trying to compile the model using the below line of code.

```
model = TFBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate, epsilon=1e-08)
loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
metric = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy('accuracy')

callbacks = [tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=OUTPUT_FOLDER+"\\bert_model.h5",
                                                        save_weights_only=True,
                                                        monitor='val_loss',
                                                        mode='min',
                                                        save_best_only=True)]

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=[metric])
```

While compiling the code, I get the type error.

TypeError: Invalid keyword argument(s) in `compile`: {'steps_per_execution'}

The transformers package version im currently using is 4.11.3. The above code worked like a charm when I used tranformers 4.10.2

How do i get this to work with 4.11.3?

Comment: Having the same problem. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: @Sammy I havent found the solution yet. I did try updating the tf version but throws an error.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your TensorFlow version is not up to date. I had the same issue a few hours ago. I updated my TensorFlow version to the newest version (and CUDA and cudnn to the respective version) and now it works fine. So just update your TensorFlow version and you will be fine.

Edit: I went from TensorFlow 2.3.0 to 2.7.0

Answer (score 1):

This issue also arise when using an up to date Tensorlflow version, such as v2.8.0, and disabling eager execution.

```py
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```

This happens because keras models rely on [training_v1.py](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/c8b3ffd02a3c3983e02274a299365ac384105366/keras/engine/training_v1.py#L216-L225) instead of [training.py](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/c8b3ffd02a3c3983e02274a299365ac384105366/keras/engine/training.py#L524-L533) when using graph execution, and the former does not provide the steps_per_execution option.

The file training.py implements the base class for Keras models when using eager execution (default) and training_v1.py does the same for graph mode. While they intend to provide the same functionality, the option steps_per_execution is not available for graph mode though.

Comment: Your answer serves as a complement of information together with the post before this, although you would need to add more relevant details of the files you are indicating.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I edited the original answer.